# application crash when cursor return rows more than 200

Tags: android, sqlite

application crash when cursor return rows more than 200

this is code

```
   private void Search() {
        EditText EditText_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        searchText = EditText_search.getText().toString();
        if(searchText!="")
        {
        fetch.clear();
        mDbHelper = new rewaya.books.shiaa.database.DatabaseAdapter(
                getApplication());
        try {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.selectQuery(GenerateSQLCommand(searchText));
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        if (count > 0) {    this.startManagingCursor(cursor);
        String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "SectionName", "Text" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ID, R.id.SectionName, R.id.Text };
        final SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.item_search_result, cursor, columns, to);
        ListView chapterListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchlist);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            ArraySearchResult = new ArrayList<RowStructure>();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                fetch.add(new RowStructure(cursor.getInt((cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("_id"))), formatText(cursor
                        .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SectionName"))),
                        formatText(cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex("Text")))));
                RowStructure ShourtCutRow = new RowStructure(cursor.getInt(0),
                        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
                ArraySearchResult.add(ShourtCutRow);                
                cursor.moveToNext();}



                }

            Collections.reverse(ArraySearchResult);
            adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(SearchActivity.this,
                    R.id.searchResultListview, fetch);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    startParagraphPagerActivity(position);

                }
            });
            mDbHelper.close();
            this.stopManagingCursor(cursor);
        }
        else 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "لم يتم العثور على نتائج بحث", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }

        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "يرجى ادخال كلمة البحث", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
```

04-22 15:55:23.520: D/AndroidRuntime(8829): Shutting down VM
04-22 15:55:23.520: W/dalvikvm(8829): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bdb1f8)
04-22 15:55:23.527: E/AndroidRuntime(8829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 15:55:23.527: E/AndroidRuntime(8829): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/rewaya.books.shiaa/databases/fekr.db (conn# 0) already closed
04-22 15:55:23.527: E/AndroidRuntime(8829):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2214)

Comment: Could you provide more code? I see that you operate on closed cursor.

Comment: I don't understand your code but I think you operate on the same instance of the cursor in SimpleCursorAdapter and in the loop and I one place cursor is closed which cause the crash.